# Deciphering C pointer code

Tags: c

I'm new to C and came across some code dealing with pointers and could use some help deciphering it. What does this mean? It appears to be casting variable p to be a pointer to an int. I'm confused by the (int *) code.

```
*(int *)p = 0x113
```

Answer (score 7):

It casts `p` to a pointer-to-int, and then stores the (integer) value `0x113` at the referenced location.

Answer (score 4):

When you run across something like this, the best way to approach it is to separate it an take it one step at a time. Start with what is immediately casting the variable at issue and go from there. Here is it

```
*  (int *)  p
```

Starting at the middle, you have a cast to a pointer of type int:

```
(int *)
```

The cast is operating on variable `p`. So you know you are casting `p` to `int *`. So the following just says cast variable `p` to type `int *`:

```
(int *)p
```

Then the last piece of the puzzle is the `*` which says dereference the whole 'shebang'. So in its final form, you are simply dereferencing `p` which has been cast to `int *`:

```
*(int *)p
```

Answer (score 2):

It says "treat p as a pointer to type int, then store value of 0x113 in the 4 bytes pointed to by p" (assuming int is 4 bytes).
The effect is that if, for example, p is declared as a pointer to char, this command will be able to modify 4 bytes instead of just one (size of char).